# Permalink in Wordpress loop outputs <A> for each new line

Tags: permalinks

I'm using the following loop to pull my posts, the a is wrapped around the div to make sure it links to the post when clicked.

```
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 6
)); 

while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>


<div class="carousel-cell" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="<?php the_field('banner_afbeelding'); ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
<div class="inner-wrap">
    <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <h4><?php the_category(''); ?></h4>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

This is the HTML output I'm getting:

```
<div class="carousel-cell is-selected flickity-bg-lazyloaded" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; background-image: url(&quot;https://puranenschilder-totaalonderhoud.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/2-bas-H.jpg&quot;);">

<a href="https://puranenschilder-totaalonderhoud.nl/rozengracht/"></a>
<div class="inner-wrap">
    <a href="https://puranenschilder-totaalonderhoud.nl/rozengracht/"></a>
        <div class="box">
            <a href="https://puranenschilder-totaalonderhoud.nl/rozengracht/"></a>
            <div class="inner"><a href="https://puranenschilder-totaalonderhoud.nl/rozengracht/"></a>
                <h3><a href="https://puranenschilder-totaalonderhoud.nl/rozengracht/"></a><a href="https://puranenschilder-totaalonderhoud.nl/rozengracht/">Rozengracht</a></h3>
                <h4>
                <ul class="post-categories">
                <li>    
                    <a href="https://puranenschilder-totaalonderhoud.nl/category/buitenschilderwerk/" rel="category tag">Buitenschilderwerk</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a difference between `get_permalink()` and `the_permalink()` - you need to use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `the_category()` outputs a list of categories, *with links*. So it's outputting its own `<a>` tags, and you cannot put `<a>` tags inside other `<a>` tags. It's not valid HTML.

What you're seeing is the browser's attempt to produce valid HTML based on invalid markup. HTML is very resilient, and invalid markup will not cause it to crash. THe browser just does things like this. If you look at the raw HTML returned for the page in the Network tabs of the browser's developer tools you will see what HTML your template actually created.

If you want to output the list of a post's categories without links, you will need to do something like this:

Answer (score -1):

if you use **get_permalink()** then you need to user echo and **the_permalink()** you did not use to echo.

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>
```

code:-

```
<div class="carousel-cell" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="<?php the_field('banner_afbeelding'); ?>">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <h4><?php the_category(''); ?></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: When using the provided code. I'm still getting 'random' <a> tags as output. I've updated the original post with that output.

Comment: There's no reason this would have caused the original issue.